# How to support SAML for user authentication

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, saml-2.0

I am working on an enterprise web application (Java/J2EE based) which currently supports native authentication and authorization through acegi security.(version 1)
We are planning to add SAML based SSO authentication to the application.

In theory it looks simple, (see the image below)
[image: SAML flow]

But I just could not find any concrete way/tutorial/step by step solution in order to add SAML support to my application. Google pointed me to OpenSAML manual (posted the link below), but not much help there as well.
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual

Am I missing something very simple here. Please help or point me to the resources.

Comment: Shibboleth should be the right place. Have you looked - in the products section - at the Identity Provider and the Service Provider ?

Comment: I've gone down the path of rolling my own, using Shibboleth's OpenSAML libraries. I don't recommend it. Look for a solution you can integrate; any of the suggestions already posed are good places to start. Just don't start with the raw API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:

[SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html)

and

[SAML : A SAML stack](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-stack.html)

There's links there for a number of ways to add client side SAML support.

Or you can go the "agent" route using something like OpenAM, Shibboleth (as above) Ping Identity etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys. I'll be trying the above links and will come back with the results.

Comment: I habe finished the SAML integration to our web application. We were able to do that by using OpenAM fedlets (the documentation provided was pretty good.) Also we were successful using spring security saml extension as well. One word of advice for spring security guys. The whole world is still not on maven (ant is still more used than maven). I had to juggle to get all the relevant jars for spring security saml extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the Shibboleth route, that's fine, but I'd recommend against starting with the APIs (the link you posted). Start with the installation guide, which [you can find here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Installation).

Rolling your own implementation from the APIs that Shibboleth provides is not a trivial proposition; you're better off integrating an existing product, like Shibboleth or Ping Identity or the like. There's a lot of hidden complexity in the relatively simple SAML protocol, and you'll spend a lot of time navigating a great many pitfalls if you try to build your own. I've done it, I know.

Of course, if you have a lot of time, it might be worthwhile learning the protocol, as after building my own IdP on top of OpenSAML I know quite a lot about the SAML standards, both good and bad, which has proved valuable in my current position. However, this is not the quickest solution by far. Best of luck, whichever route you choose!